# Handling Connection Error when using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Hope you're all well.

I'm trying to extract tweets continuously for a long period of time, using tweepy library. For that I have a python script with an infinite loop running. The only problem is that everytime the connection fails, for any possible reason, my script will crash and I will have to restart it. So I wanted to do it robust specially to connection errors,and for that I am using try...except condition but it doesn't seem to work. I already tried everything I found online and nothing worked, can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   consumer_key, consumer_secret,
   access_token, access_token_secret
)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

city = 'LX'
country = 'PT'
coord = '38.736946,-9.142685'
radius = '25km'

while True:
    today = datetime.now()

    if len(str(today.month)) == 1:
        month = str(0) + str(today.month)
    else:
        month = str(today.month)    
    n=10
    tweets=tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q="",geocode=coord+','+radius,tweet_mode="extended").items(n)
 
    fname = f'{country}_{city}_{today.day}{month}{str(today.year)[2:]}.json'

    with open(fname, 'a') as outfile:
        for tweet in tweets:
            try: 
                outfile.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
                outfile.write('\n')
            except:
                os.system(f'echo error >> log_file.log')
                print('error')
                pass
        outfile.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

(this is a sample code, so it's possible it has some typos)
In the except clause I already tried with `tweepy.TweepyException` but without result too. To simulate a connection error I turn off my internet while running the script but I keep receiving an error and the script crashes, instead of just giving my the except block and continue running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used to run tweepy for months at a time. This is my brute force approach to the problem:
create a file called `forever.py` or whatever you want and use popen

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
arg1 = sys.argv[2]
while True:
    print("\nStarting " + filename)
    p = Popen("python3 " + filename + ' ' + arg1, shell=True)
    p.wait()
```

Then from the command line :

```
python3 forever.py yourpythonscript.py arg1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So what I should do is create a file with exactly this first part of code in your answer (changing the filename to the script I want to run) and then give it as argument the script I'm trying to run? And this will solve the problem of restarting the script everytime it fails?

Comment: Create a file with this first snippet. Then when you run this file, you pass your script as the argument. ie ```python3 thisfile yourfile```. If your file stops running, this will start it again. hence the name 'forever'

Comment: Ok makes sense, thank you! So this would be a python file right? Like forever.py , so to run it I would do ```python3 forever.py myfile.py```? And just another question, if I have arguments in my python file, can I put them after?

Comment: I never used .py on forever, but it shouldn't be a problem. If you have args that you pass you need to add extra logic. I will update answer.

Comment: So your forever file usually is in what format? Thank you very much again!

Comment: you see the #! at the top? its a directive to tell what interpreter to use. in this case it was the file telling bash to run this in python3. i didnt put an extension on forever, i called it forever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246864/discussion-between-filipa-and-1extralime).